# Filter by properties of nested array - Knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have some problems filtering a nested array with Knockout out.

I want to be able to filter the array by 'tag-names' as well as 'name'.

i.e. type in 'whal' and all object that contain a tag with that name is filtered in grid.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/king_s/fj9L3wjz/3/

```html
<input data-bind="value: searchQuery, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

<div data-bind="foreach: filter" class="grid">
    <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
</div>
```

```js
(function(){
    var ViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        var obj = { "id": 11, 
            "name": "mouse", 
            "tags": [{ "id": 1, 
                "name": "critter"
            }] 
        };
        var obj2 = { "id": 12, 
            "name": "dolphin", 
            "tags": [{ "id": 2,
                "name": "fish"
            }, 
            {"id": 3,
                "name": "whale"
            }] 
        };
        self.searchQuery = ko.observable("");
        self.array = ko.observableArray([obj, obj2]);
        self.filter = ko.computed(function() {
            if(!self.searchQuery()) {
                return self.array();
            } else {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.array(), function(obj) {
                    return obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase()) > -1;
                });
            }
        });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a second check for the tags:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.array(), function(obj) {
            var tagsCheck = ko.utils.arrayFilter(obj.tags, function(tag) {
            return tag['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase()) > -1});

                return (obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase()) > -1) || tagsCheck.length;
                });
```

also check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj9L3wjz/4/)

Comment: @user3116167 NP. Please upvote if you liked the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate through your sub objects like this:

```
self.filter = ko.computed(function() {
  if (!self.searchQuery()) {
    return self.array();
  } else {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.array(), function(obj) {
      var value = obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase());
      var compensation = 0; // Compensate for how many tags there are
      obj.tags.forEach(function (tag) {
        compensation--;
        value += tag.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase());
      })
      // Final value is greater than -1 + (-1 * number of tags)
      return value > -1 + compensation;
    });
  }
});
```

Try it here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0f89443/)

**EDIT**

I was inspired to update my answer to the following so it looks cleaner:

```
self.filter = ko.computed(function() {
  if (!self.searchQuery()) {
    return self.array();
  } else {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.array(), function(obj) {
      var found = obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase()) > -1;
      obj.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
        if (tag.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          found = true;
        }
      });
      return found;
    });
  }
});
```

Try it here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4j476zv7/)

Comment: You're a very close second, and I do like your answer, even though I don't understand it lol

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I like it. Mine was fast because it wasn't as condensed as yours lol

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [KO filters extender](https://gist.github.com/webketje/3bd7f383f4ec074d1eb3) a while ago which helps with these kind of jobs. It creates a `filtered` property on the observableArray and allows flexible cumulation of filters.

In your HTML you'd do:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: array.filtered" class="grid">
```

And your JS would be:

```
self.array = ko.observableArray([obj, obj2]).extend({filters: {
  search: function(obj) {
    var query     = self.searchQuery().toLowerCase(),
        nameMatch = obj.name.toLowerCase().match(query),
        tagMatch  = false;
    obj.tags.forEach(function(tag, i) {
      if (tag.name.toLowerCase().match(query))
        tagMatch = true;
    });
    return nameMatch || tagMatch;
  }
}});    

self.array.toggleFilter('search', true);
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj9L3wjz/5/).